# Express update user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a basic express application with a couple of routes and a login function, now the user has a balance associated to its data which is stored in a `express-session` however when the user refreshes I want the balance to update, to do this I need to get the balance again from the database and put it in the session when the user refreshes.

I just cannot seem to find out how to handle a user refreshing.. How do you do it?

I'm using PassportJS for handling login/regristrations.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a middleware function that runs for all requests which uses the users id from the session object to look up their balance from the database and then assign the updated balance to the session object?

The middleware would be like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    // use req.session.userId to look up balance.
    // req.session.balance = lookedUpValue;
});
```

This should be placed before any routes in the app.